# Google Response Sound (Ding sound) on clicking google mic or saying Ok google

Tags: google

Why after turning off all the accessibility services the sound is disabled  and immediately after enabling accessibility of any third party app or inbuilt app ,this sound is enabled.
I (perhaps everyone , I tested 3 phones at my home ) am facing this issue since two year.
This is not an OS issue  as it occurred in Marshmallow, Noughat as well as in Oreo.

I have found only one solution on the internet reagarding this & it is "Turn on Accessibility fpe at least one app"

Comment: Could you [edit] your question and clarify it, please? As it stands it's not at all clear what the problem is. Describe the steps you took, what you wanted to happen, and what actually happened.

Comment: I am saying about the sound which Google gives on saying "OK GOOGLE".

Comment: https://www.androidpolice.com/2017/10/17/tip-get-ding-sound-ok-google-command-enabling-one-accessibility-service/